# Clustered sampling of points

Tags: python

Consider the range [0,100]. Suppose I want to sample N points from this range, but I want to "cluster" my samples around 50 (or any number in the range) and sample exponentially fewer points the closer I get to 0 or 100.

How can I accomplish this in Python?

Thanks

Comment: What does "exponentially fewer" mean in your case?

Comment: I mean I want more points around 50 and fewer points everywhere else. So there might be a modest number of points near 25 and 75, but only a few near 0 and 100.

Exponential in the sense of a bell curve. In this case, 50 is the "mean".

Comment: Then you should sample from a normal distribution centered at 50 (but drop the outliers that are outside of your range).

Answer (score 0):

You can sample from a normal distribution centered at 50. Here's a way to accomplish your task in NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
N = 100
stddev = 10 # Play with it
your_range = 0,100
midpoint = sum(your_range) / 2
samples = np.random.normal(midpoint, stddev, N)
good_samples = samples[(samples <= your_range[1]) &\
                       (samples >= your_range[0])]
```

Answer (score 0):

As DyZ says you can use a normal distribution, but the support of a normal distribution is -inf to inf. You can also use a beta distribution, who's support is 0 to 1, then multiply by 100 to get 0 to 100. Select your shape parameters by looking at a few examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution

something like:

```
import numpy as np
a = 20
b = 20
num_samples = 10
samples = np.round(np.random.beta(a, b, num_samples) * 100)
```

To get a feel for the shape you want you can try this site: https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1180573226. With a beta your distribution is centered at a / (a + b). In your case if you want it centered in the middle (50) make sure a = b. Then the higher numbers you use, the "peakier" the distribution will be.

Comment: The problem with beta is that it is either asymmetric (skewed) or not sharp enough to provide "exponentially fewer" samples far away from the mode.

Comment: You could use a beta with a=b=20 to get a pretty peaky distribution that isn't skewed ...

Comment: Agree. Perhaps beta is a betta choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you literally mean exponentially fewer points, a cheap solution could work like this:

Sample values according to an exponential distribution, 
shift the center to 50 and 
randomly change the direction of the spread:

```
import numpy as np

n = 1000
offset = 50
spread = np.random.exponential(scale=np.log(offset), size=n)
direction = (-1)**np.random.randint(2, size=n)

x = offset + spread * direction
# Trim the outliers
x = x[(x <= 100) & (x >= 0)]
```

Comment: And don't forget to trim the outliers.

Comment: The outliers really must be removed, not replaced with 0 and 100. Otherwise, you may end up having many samples at 0 and 100.